# How to see local and auto variables values on remote debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

sAs I wrote in the subject I can't see that values of variables in remote debug mode.
The window of auto and locals are empty during debug.

Any ideas why? and how can I solve it?
When I'm trying to add a watch on a variable I get:
`Internal error in the expression evaluator`

Comment: Any progress? (I use VS2012) I read Update2 should fix it but I have update 3.. doesnt work.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22596776/908336

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug in visual studio 2012 . Apparently it works with vs 2010 . VS 2012 Update 2 fixed it but update 3 broke it again according to some posts on connect

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/764708

Update :

I was not able to get it working in visual studio 2012 even after installing update 3. But then i installed visual studio 2013 and everything works fine. I can step into the code and add watch