# Visual studio 2012 - locals have disappeared

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012

While debugging VS2012 I have found that I can no longer access variable values:

- The Locals window does not show anything (pictured below).
- The Watch window tells me "Unable to evaluate the expression" for any expression (also pictured below). My personal favourite is that it cannot evaluate `true`.
- And mousing-over any variable does not show any values tool-tip.

[image: Image showing no locals]

**What I've tried:**

Restarting Visual Studio

Restarting my computer

Checking that the loaded modules shows debug symbols are loaded

Uninstalling the TeamCity plugin that I installed yesterday

Looking under Tools/Options/Debugging for anything obvious (and disabling other extensions that had been working fine)

EDIT: I've also tried creating a new solution.

I've also noticed that the call stack shows several blank lines where I presume there are supposed to be external method names (pictured above) - I'm not sure if this is relevant, but it is worth mentioning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've eventually managed to sort this out by myself - so I'll give my solution here in case anyone else has the same problem:

I found that in Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols was pointing to an old NuGet symbol server. Somehow a wrong symbol server looked like it was taking down the entire Locals and Immediate Window systems.

Updating the symbol server fixed my problems.

Comment: Worked for me on Visual Studio 2015 as well.

Answer (score 9):

I will add this answer as I had the same problem with a different resolution.

I had mistakenly closed the locals window and could not find it as it was not with other windows under the VIEW menu.  I found it under the DEBUG menu Windows option.

or Optionally:

Ctrl+Alt+V, L

Comment: Its not problem with locating watch window. This is not the answer for the problem being mentioned by OP.

Answer (score 3):

I will add this answer as I had the same problem with a different resolution.

I got this too in a Web project. Neither restarting Visual Studio or any other solution in this thread sovled it.

My solution was to restart IIS. After that I rebuilt the project and started it and got locals to work again.

Comment: Not sure why this got down voted, this fixed my problem. I'm assuming restarting the machine would have also worked.

Answer (score 3):

Please check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275457/visual-studio-2013-stopped-showing-variable-values-when-debugging).

In a nutshell, you need to open: **Tools > Options > Debugger > General**, and enable the flag [***Use Managed Compatibility Mode***] at the end of the list.

Answer (score 2):

That happens sometime when your **Optimize Code** box is ticked in project properties under Build section.

Comment: I've checked that I'm not optimising the code for this project, but thanks

Comment: These are both 'Variable out of scope' errors. I'm getting 'Unable to evaluate the expression' errors. And besides, `true` should never be out of scope

Comment: this helped to see unused variables in Locals window

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 on Windows 10 while using remote debugging.

According to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628412/how-to-see-local-and-auto-variables-values-on-remote-debugging) the locals/variables are broken in the remote debugging tools.

*I haven't found a solution yet, but I'm going to switch to Visual Studio 2015 so I haven't really been looking for it either...*