# Visual Studio 2015 Community - Unable to show variables during debug WIndows Phone 8.1 app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, vs-community-edition

I'm working on Windows Phone 8.1 app (in WinRT, not silverlight), and Visual didn't want to show any variable in scope during Debug that application. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community and my own phone (I don't have installed emulator).

I already try any tricks from [Visual Studio 2013 stopped showing variable values when debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275457/visual-studio-2013-stopped-showing-variable-values-when-debugging) but without any reactions. I'm not sure if that is Community version limitation or maybe bug. There is no problem during debug ASP.NET MVC application.

It is so painfull if I'm unable to watch my variables... the only think that I can do is set a breakpoint nothing else.

Update: Still same issue, but it's worked today for an hour and now again broken...

Comment: Why this is viewed only 12 times ;/

Comment: Happens to me from time to time, cleaning the project and rebuilding the solution sometimes helps, sometime not and then it fixes itself after a few days. Frustrating.

Comment: For me that wasn't working since begin

Comment: How much RAM do you have? Are there any exceptions in the console? Do you run as Administrator?  How big is your project, and does it create a lot of new objects? This may be related to memory issues. Restarting VS fixes this for me, but it sounds like you run into memory issues quickly. Try outputting the memory usage like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750574/how-to-get-memory-available-or-used-in-c-sharp