# Visual Studio 2015 no local variables in locals window

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, visual-studio-2015, locals

I have recently migrated from Visual Studio C# Express 2010 (WinForms) to Visual Studio 2015 Community, i was able to build my projects, but now when i start debugging the locals window doesn't show any variables at all.

My solution configuration is:
Configuration: Debug
Platform: x86
Build: Checked
Deploy: Unchecked

Code analysis settings:
Configuration: Active Configuration
Platform: Active Platform

I have tried Tools>Options>Debugging>General
Checked "Use Managed Compatibility Mode"
Checked "Use the legacy C# and VB expression evaluators"

Solution cleaning & Rebuilding but still no luck.

Comment: What stack frame are you paused at?

Comment: The call stack windows doesn't show any content either

Comment: Are you paused? What modes have you attached to? (Managed, Native?) What does the Threads window show?

Comment: Man i feel so dumb, i forgot to pause.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue upgrading from express. My problem was resolved after I updated Visual Studio 2015 Community to [Update 1](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx). I am not 100% if that will resolve your issue, but it fixed mine.

Comment: Maybe some of the answers in [this threaad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023194/visual-studio-2012-locals-have-disappeared) will help?