# "Internal error in the expression evaluator"

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I've encountered a problem in expression evaluator of visual studio 2015 that says "Internal error in the expression evaluator", after some investigations I found that this is caused by an assembly that is loaded using reflection. This assembly wouldn't throw any exceptions but after that, vs exp evaluator will fail.
This is not the only assembly that I load, there are some good working ones that don't influent the evaluator.

To overcome this issue I had to check 'Menu > options > debugging > Use Managed Compatibility Mode' but this disables the 'Edit & Continue' feature, what can I do?

Properties of the causer assembly:

- its name is the same as the main assembly
   (i changed its name but nothing happened)
- all of my projects are using dotNet 4.5
- all root namespaces are same
   (all of the assemblies are so)

Thanks!

Comment: I´m having the same problem Legacy option didn´t fix it.

Comment: Similar question [Get "Internal error in the expression evaluator" on "Add watch" function when trying to debug WCF service code (MSVS 2013)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21854426)

Comment: The same happens to me when trying to test a Web API 2 controller...

Comment: I have a similar problem when debugging c++ cli. For me, it starts after I use SqlCommand::Open (does not depend if in the same assembly or in another one). Turning on managed compatibility mode is not an option for me, because then natvis does not work any more, and I cannot inspect for instance stl collections, I use in the native part.

Comment: I had to uncheck both options to get rid of the error using vs 2017

Answer (score 80, accepted):

That sounds like a bug in the expression evaluator.  For a better workaround, instead of checking "Use Managed Compatibility Mode", check "Use the legacy C# and VB expression evaluators".  This should enable you to continue using Edit and Continue as well as other features added within the last few releases.

In terms of the "Internal error in expression evaluator", can you please open an issue by going to Help -> Send Feedback -> Report a problem?  That will help us fix the problem in future releases.

Comment: I had the same issue - checking the Legacy option fixed it.

Comment: What features do you lose when using Legacy evaluators?

Comment: The legacy option is not enabled on my machine. Is there another solution to this problem?

Comment: @Pallavi Is the checkbox disabled?  The checkbox is disabled if the debugger is already running.  You'll have to stop debugging to change the option.

Comment: Yeah I was in the middle of a debugging session. It started working sometime later without doing anything though! That's visual studio...

Comment: This worked for me, though in my case, the problem happens only when attached to a remote process using the Remote Debugger.

Comment: I had to uncheck both options to get rid of the error using vs 2017.

Comment: I had to uncheck this for it to fix my problem as well.. Unchecked both "Use Legacy..." and "Managed Compatibility Mode".. back to where I was :-)

Comment: Switching to 'Use the legacy C# and VB expression evaluators' fixed this problem for me in VS 2019

Answer (score 37):

Just extending on the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34550540/3195477) provided by *Patrick Nelson*. For Visual Studio 2015+ as inquired, the steps are as follows.

If you're debugging at the moment, this option will be unavailable. Stop the debugger.

Go to **Tools** -> **Options**

[image: VS Options]

and here under the Options select **Debug** -> **General** and scroll down to find the *...legacy C# expression..* option:

[image: VS Options Debug Legacy options]

More information is provided here:

[Switching to Managed Compatibility Mode](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2013/10/16/switching-to-managed-compatibility-mode-in-visual-studio-2013/)

**Note:** There are also some serious drawbacks that occur from switching to the legacy mode. Especially **Runtime Reflection** of the implemented Interfaces becomes almost an impossibility or extremely inconvenient. There are also other Reflection methods which will throw errors.

Comment: PERFECT!! this was the solution for .NET core code. I have to switch it back on when working with old .NET framework code. (but thats fine i can live with it )

Comment: Thanks for showing where to go to set the option.  The other people who answered must have assumed that everyone knew.

Answer (score 21):

I finally figured out what created this problem in my Visual Studio!

**The quick fix is to delete the debug object favorites from the "Documents/Visual Studio xx/Visualizers" folder and restart Visual Studio.**

[image]
When you "pin" a variable in the debugger, Visual Studio saves a 'favorite' json object for it.

**It appears that there is a bug in Visual Studio which corrupts the 'favorite' for some child variables that are dynamic in nature** (not exactly sure of the conditions though).
[image]

Comment: Worked for me in Visual Studio 2022

Comment: Omg you are lifesaver I would have never found it. Worked in Visual Studio 2022 when i'm using alot of pins, my debugger stop watching variables.. yikes!

Comment: Works like a charm. Looks like the bug is still present in 2022 17.6.4

Comment: Worked for me in Visual Studio 2022 as well

Answer (score 3):

For me checking "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" option worked. I was also seeing question marks when hovering over variables, instead of properties and values

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by simply resetting my visual studio settings by going to: to Tools->Import and Export Settings and selecting to reset to default settings

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with VS2019. I ended up deleting my Documents/Visual Studio 2019 folder. Hope this might help someone, one day. Cost me a day.

PS. Probably not required to delete all, and of course not your projects (if they're in there), but in my case, everything in there was autogenerated by VS.

I of course tried all solutions mentioned here, and even reinstalling VS didn't work. Refactoring the class to another name was the 'trigger' which made me think there must be some cache, despite cleaning symbols and such didnt work.

Comment: I had pinned a property on an object I was debugging which prevented the intellisense from working and the "hover over" popup wouldn't work. When I tried to add a watch I would get the above error. Deleting the folder cleared the cache and fixed it for me. I had to setup all the pinned properties on each object again, but at least this fixed it!

Comment: A bit late.. but I had this once as well. There's a file called 'ObjectFavorites.json' in your 'Visualizers' folder. This file contains all those 'pinned values', and you could have deleted the line which was causing the trouble. 

PS. This file is only visible after there's at least one pinned value/property.

Comment: I'm getting this in VS 2019. Didn't have the json file. Tried deleting the .bin file in that folder, but it didn't fix anything.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to evaluate lambda expression on List<> and had such error ("Internal error in the expression evaluator"). I was using VS2015, so lambda expressions were allowed. It turns out expression evaluator was lacking of Linq library. I added

```
using System.Linq;
```

to my current class and voilà! Lambda evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the "internal error in the expression evaluator" error when I was debugging in release mode instead of in debug mode.  I had changed it to Release when publishing to production and forgot to change it back to Debug.

[image: Release Mode]

[image: Debug Mode]

Answer (score -1):

Check your use of the `[DebuggerBrowsable]` attribute; I found a minimal case in VisualStudio 2017 15.5 and posted it [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/196121/debugger-ee-internal-error-if-debuggerbrowsable-wh.html).

In this particular case, the expression evaluator (EE) crash appears related to the `[DebuggerBrowsable]` attribute applied to a property overriding a field of the same name. This will account for *some* percentage of the cases that people are experiencing out there, but there's no way of knowing how many are due to this specific issue until it gets fixed.

The full and complete demonstration example is shown in the image (and included below for good measure)

[image]

Machine-readable copy of the code in the image:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program { static void Main() => new _derived(); }

abstract class _base
{
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    public Object trace;
};

class _derived : _base
{
    public _derived() => Debugger.Break();      // <-- vs2017 EE crash when stopped here

    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    new public Object trace => base.trace;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I had 2 same dll files in 2 different folders (seems, one dll was not correct). Deleting the .dll and rebuilding solution solved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

In my case the data I was attempting to inspect was extremely large, a string which unexpectantly had hundreds of megabytes of data in it. The issue wasn't apparent when the amount of data being inspected was reasonable.