# Visual Studio 2022 - Values while debugging (DataTips) not working while hover on properties c#

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2022

my question is about displaying values during debugging. My Visual Studio version is:
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.4.2

Since Visual Studio 2022, I noticed that I do not see values when hovering with the mouse on complex types in the debugger.

I remember that in older version you could always see the value of a variable by just hovering over the expression.

Now this only works on the root element. As soon as I want to see a property value of it, I now have to select the whole expression up to that point with the mouse.

Screenshot 1: "Password" has a value
[image: property is set]

Screenshot 2: When I hover the mouse over Password, the value is not evaluated and displayed.
[[image: hovering on property not shwoing value]

Screenshot 3: Only when I select everything, the value is displayed.
[image: hovering on property working when selecting]

What can I do to get the same behavior as before? Just hover the mouse over it without selecting the whole expression.

Thanks for your help!

Research on the Internet brought up a few approaches, none of which could solve my problem.

In the Visual Studio settings I found no option to get the desired behavior

Answer (score 11):

Close VS, then delete the `.vs` temp folder in your solution directory.

Comment: This was helped me to solve the issue

Comment: Vs2022 does not show variable values in my case after closing and deleting solution .vs temp folder

Answer (score 7):

Visual Studio 2022 version 17.8.4 (Released 9th January 2024) fixes this.

[Visual Studio 2022 v 17.8.4 Release Notes](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Visual-Studio-2022-Release-178-Hovering/10518414)

> 

Update (new answer): This issue is definitely related to screen resolution/scaling. I have 3 monitors. My "main" monitor is my laptop screen (3456 * 2160 @ 300% scaling) and my other two monitors are 1920* 1080 at 100% scaling.

Visual Studio always opens on my main screen (laptop) and then I move it to the right hand monitor afterwards. It seems that VS does its calculations when it starts up, because what I **think** is happening is the tooltips are showing, but they are not visible because they are off screen in the wrong place.

I have found 2 solutions for me that require no resetting:

1. Close the laptop lid before running VS (assuming you have your machine power settings set up to ignore a lid close when plugged in). This forces VS to open on one of the monitors where I run it anyway.
2. Set the monitor where I want to run VS as my "main" monitor (System -> Display -> Multiple Monitors -> Make this my main display). This used to be my laptop, but now it is the screen where I like to run VS.
   This works every time now.

> 

Old answer:

You need to go to Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General as [Jingmiao Xu-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17296043/jingmiao-xu-msft) says.

This problem seems to be a bug though as mine was already ticked and I couldn't see the values.

However, unticking "Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls", exiting, then re-ticking fixed the problem for me (as did "repair", which takes ages).

Update: My VS has gone back to its old (broken)  behavior again.  Also, the tick -> untick -> tick method doesn't always work.

I have found executing this command to be more reliable, but clunky as it resets setting that you might want to keep (which you can also do by exporting those settings and re-importing).

This seems to work:

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"/ResetUserData

The ResetUserData switch isn't documented but I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823385/what-does-visual-studio-devenv-exe-resetuserdata-do-exactly):

Comment: The 2nd option worked for me in VS2022

Answer (score 2):

My solution was in resolution screens. Try to change scale of one of the screen or resolution. In my case I just decrease scale to 100% on small screen from 125%.

My answer was here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/datatip-is-not-shown-when-using-two-screens-with-d/649598

Comment: can you provide the answer here, now we need to look for it ourselves

Comment: omg this is the answer!!  Can't believe it was a just a glitch after all...  Mine worked when I brought it to 4k monitor.

Answer (score 1):

I just downgraded the Visual Studio back to previous version and it worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35293612)

Comment: If a guy doesn't have reputation  to comment and he has found a workaround to the question, how should he help others then? please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem but for me it turned out my OneDrive for Business account corrupted my Documents/Visual Studio 2022/Visualizers folder.

I had to run: `chkdsk c: /r /f` in a Command Prompt, then after reboot deleted the folder.

I discovered this solution thanks to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67526748

Answer (score -1):

In your second screenshot you selected a whole line of code, so its value is not shown.

Here is my test screenshot:

1.Just hover over the property：

[image]

2.Select a whole line of code：

[image]

3.Select the property:

[image]

You can try just hovering over the property without selecting the whole line of code.

You can check the "Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls" in Tools > Options > Debugging > General:

[image]

Comment: Hello,

thank you for your comment! That's exactly my problem: simply hovering over the property doesn't work for me anymore. It only works if I select the row.

And normally it should work as you describe: Just hover over it and read the value. Any Idea?

Comment: @Justanothercoder I edited my answer, hope it can help you to solve the problem.

Comment: According to your description in the question: "Screenshot 2: When I hover the mouse over Password, the value is not evaluated and displayed." But the scrrenshot2 shows you selecting the whole line of code and then hovering over the property, it will not display the value of the property, you shouldn't select anything, just hover over the property. "It only works if I select the row" is that what is the case in screenshot3?

Comment: Having the same problem. Maybe it's a recent update? Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. I have these options checked too and still not working.

Comment: This was a recent update. How do I fix this damn it??

Comment: I have updated VS 2022 to version 17.8 in order to utilize .NET 8 and I am seeing the problem. I have checked the "Enable property evaluation" option and "Call string-conversion" and both are checked.  I need a fix or remedy.

Comment: I also got the same issue when I updated the vs 2022 to the latest version(17.8). what I did was close vs and delete the .vs file and rebuild and debug the project.