# Hovering over elements in debugging isn't showing debugging info in tool tip anymore since updating and installing git copilot in VS2022

Tags: visual-studio

I recently updated VS2022 to the latest version and installed Git Copilot. Since then the hovering over elements on a breakpoint, such as variables, doesn't work. I have to quickwatch or use immediate window.

E.g. [image] ([thanks justanothercoder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74685109/6938505))

Can someone give me some tips on what to try to figure out how to get it back? [Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77513353/6938505) an early January update for VS fixed an issue related to this and changed the way it works, so it's hard to diagnose. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my .vs folder in the solution location, restarted. It wasn't working, but there was another issue - I had it set to no DPI scaling before, and that was reset. So once I fixed that, I noticed the OP issue was fixed.